# Ruby on Rails 4: has_secure_password is not asking for a password confirmation when creating new user

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, passwords, activemodel

I am currently writing an app using RoR4 and am having trouble with authentication. Even though I've added `has_secure_password` to the User model, I still seem to be able to create a new user without having to provide a password confirmation.

```
2.1.2 :012 > me = User.create(:institution_id => 1, :email => "me@myschool.edu", :password => "mypassword")
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY  'me@myschool.edu' LIMIT 1
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `email`, `institution_id`, `password_digest`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-07-14 20:02:34', 'me@myschool.edu', 1, '$2a$10$sD2N.2nxhYO7egzzWxfF5.cdIZ4ds41.sU93Ja3E9Q0qAOaABdZb6', '2014-07-14 20:02:34')
(8.2ms)  COMMIT
=> #<User id: 5, institution_id: 1, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, email: "me@myschool.edu", blurb: nil, facebook_link: nil, facebook_token: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$sD2N.2nxhYO7egzzWxfF5.cdIZ4ds41.sU93Ja3E9Q0...", api_key: nil, active: false, created_at: "2014-07-14 20:02:34", updated_at: "2014-07-14 20:02:34", authentication_token: nil>
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't `has_secure_password` always require a password confirmation as well??

Thanks for the help

Comment: are you including `gem 'bcrypt'` ? and what does you user model contains ?

Comment: I do have `'bcrypt'` installed. I actually decided to use custom validations as I needed to treat some aspects of the authentication in a special way. I am now using bcrypt to generate a password_salt and password_hash for an extra layer of security. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you followed these things:

add `gem 'bcrypt'` to gem file.

Next:

have a `password_digest` attribute

Next:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

Then you can test it:

```
user = User.new(name: 'david', password: '', password_confirmation: 'nomatch')
user.save                                                       # => false, password required
user.password = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe'
user.save                                                       # => false, confirmation doesn't match
user.password_confirmation = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe'
user.save                                                       # => true
user.authenticate('notright')                                   # => false
user.authenticate('mUc3m00RsqyRe')                              # => user
User.find_by(name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'notright')      # => false
User.find_by(name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'mUc3m00RsqyRe') # => user
```